# PDF doesn't show in UIWebView after Renamed App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiwebview

I have an App that displays a PDF in a UIWebView that is stored in the App itself.

All working fine! Until I renamed my App. The App started off being called PDFApp, then I changed it to Micro PDF, and again all worked fine.

the client then changed their minds and wanted it to be called "MIC Flooring", but when i do this the PDF does not load in the UIWebView. Very weird! everything else works as expected. If I changed the named back to Micro PDF then it works fine again.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Thanks

Sam

Comment: That sounds really weird. Have you tried Product-> Clean?

Comment: Yes, I have cleaned all targets, restarted Xcode, deleted all data off device and restarted. Its weird that without changing anything apart from the Name of the App can cause this...

Comment: Have you tried to see if the file exists before handing it over to the UIWebView by using `fileExistsAtPath:` method of `NSFileManager`?

Comment: the thing is it works absolutely fine before the name change, so i know it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you cannot have a space in your Project name - this was making the App not work properly.

instead change the Project Name to be something like - "MyAppName"

and change the 'Bundle display name' in the plist